# How to the the object at index with node.js

Tags: node.js

I am a iOS developer, I just can't find the info about how to get the first object of a array or object at index of some array.

Comment: The JS in NodeJS is for JavaScript, [try googling for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and you'll know all about Arrays :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are looking to find the object at index of an array in node.js, you can use it like

```
var objYouAreLooking = sourceArray[index];
```

This is similar to

```
 objYouAreLooking = [sourceArray objectAtIndex:index];
```

in Objective c.